# Performance of Chrome Hangouts extension

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome

I just installed the Chrome extension for Google Hangouts. Since then, I experience a lot more CPU usage of the chrome process(es). Up to 100% at times!

Does anyone else experience similar issues? Is this a bug of Chrome under linux? Or is there the same issue on other operationg systems?

Just for reference: I have an Intel i5 with 4 cores.

Comment: Under which circumstances do you experience these CPU loads? Generally when browsing the web or specifically when using Google+ and Google hangout?

Comment: I tested this with just one page of static content and hangouts open, so I would definitely say that the issue originates from hangouts

Comment: Have the same issue on the latest Firefox. Hangouts by firefox process is making my computer unusable, everything starts to lag badly (in Chrome you have different process for each page opened). Reverting to old chat fixes the problem. Maybe we should report bug to google somewhere? I would like to use Hangouts, but I can't.

Comment: @Glutanimate in my case Hangouts opened in browser tab are causing problems generally when browsing the web, but also Firefox process is taking so much resources that my whole computer is lagging.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my gmail tab was causing >100% cpu usage most of the time after I enabled Google Hangouts. I don't see the same issue in Firefox and have tried disabling all extensions/other tabs in Chrome to no avail.

Reverting to the old style chat fixed the problem.

(I know that's not really a solution as I don't know how much longer the old style chat will be available, but it will help until the problem is really fixed.)

Comment: Same for me, ended up uninstalling the extension and going back to the chat provided in g+/gmail

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing with Chrome for Windows (Win 7 Ultimate) and Chrome for Linux (Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal). Chrome was taking a full core of my i7 most of the time, and it didn't seem to be possible to kill the process. Removing Google Hangout Extension on Chrome crashed the system on Windows, but it fixed the "processor leaking" on both platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @Braiam A major focus of this question is on whether or not these issues are common; it explicitly asks if others have experienced them. So this probably *is* an answer. But I think this is one factor suggesting the question here should really be a bug report (or forum post), and closed as a bug or as too broad.

Comment: @EliahKagan chrome had 3 mayor version update since may, if he is still experiencing problems with google hangout, it deserves a new question. Although, this issue seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @Braiam I agree. Marco T Bastos: Feel free to post a new question. It might get closed as a bug report (as might this question); that will depend on the details you provide, and what people think. If it is closed, that's not a problem; often there's no way to know if something is a bug before posting about it.